# Java: How can I add an object in a List with user input?

Tags: java, list

I want to know how I can add an object with user input in an array list. I wrote a method called `createEmployee()`, but I want to know how to do it in a list. So I tried it with `employees.add(new Employee())`, but there I have to write my own input. However, I want the user to write his own input. I want something like this: `employees.add(new Employee(identity, empname, empsalary))`, but it won't work. So how can I add it with my own input and without the method createEmployee() being static?
I tried the following:

```
public class Main extends ReusaxCorp {

    public Main(String ID, String name, double grosssalary) {
        super(ID, name, grosssalary);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        createEmployee();
        ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        employees.add(new Employee());
    }

    public static Employee createEmployee(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the ID of the employee: ");
        String identity = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the name of the employee: ");
        String empname = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the gross salary of the employee: ");
        double empsalary = input.nextDouble();

        Employee Employee = new Employee(identity, empname, empsalary);
        return Employee;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? what problem you are facing?

Comment: do you want like a form with a textbox where users can enter data, which then gets saved to your list?

Comment: When you call your method, you're ignoring the result of that method: `createEmployee();`

Comment: replace employees.add(new Employee()); with employees.add(createEmployee());

Comment: Is there a way to do it without createEmployee() being static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main extends ReusaxCorp {

public Main(String ID, String name, double grosssalary) {
    super(ID, name, grosssalary);
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    Employee e = createEmployee();
    employees.add(e);
}

    public static Employee createEmployee(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the ID of the employee: ");
        String identity = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the name of the employee: ");
        String empname = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the gross salary of the employee: ");
        double empsalary = input.nextDouble();

        Employee Employee = new Employee(identity, empname, empsalary);
        return Employee;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how I can do it without the method createEmployee being static?

Comment: if you want the method `non static` you need to create an instance of the Main class, like `Main m = new Main(...); m.createEmployee()`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the constructor direct,do something like that in main method (a you mentioned you dont want to use create employee method )

```
java.util.Scanner scanner=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
boolean addingEmployee=true;
while(addingEmployee)
{
System.out.println("Please enter the employee info ID,NAME,SALARY respectively ");
employees.add(new Employee(scanner.next(),scanner.next(),scanner.nextDouble()));
System.out.println("Employee has been added" );
System.out.println("do you want to add new employee : Y,N");
if(scanner.next().charAt(0)=='N') {addingEmployee=false;}
}
```